# rails namespaced helpers isolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, helper

I found similar questions, but without answers or maybe I misunderstood some answers.
And so I venture to ask :-)

I have rails 4.2 app with two branches of inheritance, separated by namespaces.

```
Backend::BackendController < ApplicationController
Frontend::FrontendController < ApplicationController

Backend::StaticPagesHelper
Frontend::StaticPagesHelper
```

My goal: include Backend helpers in views of BackendController and
Frontend helpers in views of FrontendController. So they were **not** visible a cross Frontend helpers in BackendController and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

Setting `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` will make only the matched helper be included in a controller.

From: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

> Rails currently makes helpers available to all controllers by default.
>
> In previous versions of Rails the controller will include a helper
>   whose name matches that of the controller, e.g., `MyController` will
>   automatically include `MyHelper`. To return old behavior set
>   `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false`.